# Selecting info by breaking url using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df with a following column:

```
url
www.abc.com/
www.abc.com/ttt/page1
www.abc.com/vvv/page4/info
www.abc.com/zzz/page4
```

I would like to transform it in 4 columns like:

```
       main  prod    page   more_info 
www.abc.com   NaN     NaN   NaN
www.abc.com   ttt   page1   NaN
www.abc.com   vvv   page4   info
www.abc.com   zzz   page4
```

I tried pandas.Series.str.split and urlparse.urlsplit but did not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `str.split`

```
s=df.url.str.split('/',expand=True)
s.columns=['main', 'prod','page','more_info']
s
Out[239]: 
          main prod   page more_info
0  www.abc.com  ttt  page1      None
1  www.abc.com  vvv  page4      info
2  www.abc.com  zzz  page4      None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.extract` with regex `(?P<main>[^/]*)/?(?P<prod>[^/]*)/?(?P<page>[^/]*)/?(?P<more_info>.*)`, here each named captured group i.e.`(?P<main>[^/]*)` match a part of the url and expand to a new column in the result:

```
df.url.str.extract('(?P<main>[^/]*)/?(?P<prod>[^/]*)/?(?P<page>[^/]*)/?(?P<more_info>.*)')

#          main prod   page more_info
#0  www.abc.com
#1  www.abc.com  ttt  page1
#2  www.abc.com  vvv  page4      info
#3  www.abc.com  zzz  page4
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a few cases with only 'www.abc.com/' and in these lines I received NaN at column main. How can I fix it? I will edit the question to add this case.

Comment: You can make all the following groups optional. See the updated the regex.